# Import CSS as string in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a css file in my Angular (v5.2) project. It's included in my global styles and works just fine in the app, as I want it to. However, I also need to read this file as a string and do something else with it. Basically, to avoid repeated code, I want to be able to do:

```
import styles from 'styles.css'; // styles should be a string

// later
console.log(styles); // do something with the string
```

Is there a way I can do this?

EDIT: I am looking for a way to do this without using any requests (i.e. I don't want to move the css out of src).

Comment: you ever figure out the answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the css in assets folder you can read the file as

```
cssUrl = 'assets/styles.css';
readCssData () {
  this.http.get(this.cssUrl)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data.text())
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to do this without any extra network requests.

Answer (score 0):

To read any type of file either a JSON or CSS, you can use HttpClient Get method in angular as follows.

- Place your css in a particular folder. (ex assets/styles.css)
- Make a service call using the get method

In your componen.ts or service.ts you can get the css file using the below code

```
readCSSFile (url) {
  this.http.get(url)
    .subscribe(
      cssData => {
        console.log(cssData)
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
 }

 readCSSFile('./assets/styles.css');
```

Note: You should change the path/url based on your folder structure.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to do this without any extra network requests.